Converting a System of Three Polynomials to a Regular Chain in Mathematica
I have the following system of equations involving three polynomials in the variables XA, XB, XC with parameters a, b, c.
    system={-((b + XA + XC) (c^4 - (a^2 - b^2) (XA^2 - XB^2) - 
    c^2 (a^2 + b^2 + XA^2 + XB^2 - 2 XC^2))) + (c + XA + 
    XB) (b^4 - (a^2 - c^2) (XA^2 - XC^2) - 
    b^2 (a^2 + c^2 + XA^2 - 2 XB^2 + XC^2)) == 0,
    (a + XB + XC) (c^4 - (a^2 - b^2) (XA^2 - XB^2) - 
    c^2 (a^2 + b^2 + XA^2 + XB^2 - 2 XC^2)) - (c + XA + 
    XB) (a^4 - (b^2 - c^2) (XB^2 - XC^2) - 
    a^2 (b^2 + c^2 - 2 XA^2 + XB^2 + XC^2)) == 0,
    -2 a^2 b^2 c^2 - 2 a^4 XA^2 + 2 a^2 b^2 XA^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 XA^2 - 
    2 a^2 XA^4 + 2 a^2 b^2 XB^2 - 2 b^4 XB^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 XB^2 + 
    2 a^2 XA^2 XB^2 + 2 b^2 XA^2 XB^2 - 2 c^2 XA^2 XB^2 - 2 b^2 XB^4 + 
    2 a^2 c^2 XC^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 XC^2 - 2 c^4 XC^2 + 2 a^2 XA^2 XC^2 - 
    2 b^2 XA^2 XC^2 + 2 c^2 XA^2 XC^2 - 2 a^2 XB^2 XC^2 +
    2 b^2 XB^2 XC^2 + 2 c^2 XB^2 XC^2 - 2 c^2 XC^4 == 0};
    solutions = Solve[system /. {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5}, {XA, XB, XC}, Assumptions -> {XA > 0, XB > 0, XC > 0}]


When I replace the parameters a,b,c with numerical values (like a=3, b=4, c=5), Mathematica solves the system quickly (see the previous code), but when the parameters remain symbolic, the computation doesn't terminate.
I am trying to convert this system of three polynomials into a regular chain so that I can reduce it to one polynomial in one of the variables (say XA), another in two variables XA, XB, and the last in three variables XA,XB,XC.
I have tried using Gröbner basis to solve this, but it doesn't seem to work in this case. My question is:
How can I convert this system of equations into a regular chain in Mathematica?
Is there a way to speed up the computation for symbolic values of a,b,c, or any tricks to handle this more efficiently?

There is a triangular sets function in the Wolfram Function Repository. Or try GroebnerBasis with the option CoefficientDomain->RationalFunctiond.

Although GroebnerBasis or TriangularSets (as suggested by @DanielLichtblau) can in principle solve system, in practice the length of the answer is likely to be very large and, therefore, require a great amount of time and memory to obtain.

Using GroebnerBasis[system,{XA,XB},{XC}] works to eliminate one variable. But GroebnerBasis[system,{XC},{XA,XB}] runs for a long time and eventually returns True instead of eliminating two variables.

When you plug in values for the parameters, do you get a finite set of solutions?

Yes, with the given assumptions, I get one solution. Solve says Head: Root, and  Type is either Multivariate triangular polynomial system component (this seems to happen with irrational parameters) or Univariate Polynomial Root.

I believe that there are an infinite number of roots, if no assumptions are placed on {XA, XB, XC}.

There should only be a finite number of roots as long as the parameters a, b, c are positive and satisfy the triangle inequality. Additionally, we are only interested in positive values for XA, XB, XC. If you test with numerical values, you'll verify this.

With system as defined in the question,
Solve[system /. {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5}, {XA, XB, XC}, 
    Assumptions -> {XA > 0, XB > 0, XC > 0}]


The expression for XA
%[[1, 1, 2]] // InputForm
(* Root[5928300 + 333312*#1 - 1758884*#1^2 - 30856*#1^3 + 
   162301*#1^4 + 2170*#1^5 - 5390*#1^6 - 126*#1^7 + 45*#1^8 & , 5, 0] *)

is a root of an eighth-order polynomial.  (The corresponding solutions for XB and XC are more complicated expressions depending explicitly on XA.)  In the absence of a general solution, using GroebnerBasis or functions based on it (see question and comments), I pursued an alternative way to obtain the polynomial for XA.  First, eliminate XC.
noXC = Eliminate[system, XC]

With a LeafCount of 234657 the result is too large to be reproduced here.  Its structure is fourteen equations joined by And.  Each of the equations can be factored, and it appears that only the last factor of each equation contributes to the desired solution.
noXC1 = (Factor /@ (List @@ noXC))[[All, 1, -1]]

With a LeafCount of 48644, it too is too large to be reproduced here.  Next, determine whether the first and second equations have common roots.
Resultant[noXC1[[1]], noXC1[[2]], XB] // Factor

It is a product of nine polynomials in AX, only the final two of which might lead to positive solutions for {XA, XB, XC}.  Let us focus on the last polynomial, because it is of order eight.  Of course, this polynomial must also occur in resultants for all other pairs of noXC1 in order to yield valid roots to system.  Assume it does and solve for XA
solXA = Solve[%[[-1]] == 0, XA] // Flatten

(Still too big to reproduce here.}  Finally, compare this formula with the {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5} solution obtained in the question and reproduced at the beginning of this answer.
sXA = Select[solXA /. {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5}, #[[2]] > 0 &]


The first solution agrees with the earlier calculation.  The corresponding values of XB and XC are
sXB = Select[Solve[0 == noXC1[[1]] /. {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5} /. 
    sXA[[1]], XB, Reals] // Flatten, #[[2]] > 0 &]


sXC = Select[Solve[# /. {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5} /. sXA[[1]] /. 
    sXB[[1]], XC, Reals] // Flatten, #[[2]] > 0 &] & /@ system;
Quiet@Intersection[Sequence @@ DeleteCases[%, {}], 
    SameTest -> (N[#1] == N[#2] &)]


as desired.  We also should check whether the other sXA solutions lead to positive solutions for XB and XC.  They do not.  I have tried a few other parameter sets, which also worked well.

It's not in general possible to eliminate two variables if there are components with infinitely many solutions. Reason: if you can get a univariate polynomial in each variable, then there are finitely many solutions, as they comprisepossibly proper subset of the tuples of solutions in each variable separately. So getting a finite solution set for this case requires quotienting out the infinite sets.
Using results from solutions =  Solve[polys == 0 /. {a -> 3, b -> 7, c -> 5}, {XA, XB, XC}] it is not too hard to infer that the infinite sets arise when (XA + (XB + c)) vanishes (they have XA->-5-XB). So we can do as follows.
polys = Join[{-((b + XA + XC) (c^4 - (a^2 - b^2) (XA^2 - XB^2) - 
          c^2 (a^2 + b^2 + XA^2 + XB^2 - 2 XC^2))) + (c + XA + 
        XB) (b^4 - (a^2 - c^2) (XA^2 - XC^2) - 
        b^2 (a^2 + c^2 + XA^2 - 2 XB^2 + XC^2)), (a + XB + 
        XC) (c^4 - (a^2 - b^2) (XA^2 - XB^2) - 
        c^2 (a^2 + b^2 + XA^2 + XB^2 - 2 XC^2)) - (c + XA + 
        XB) (a^4 - (b^2 - c^2) (XB^2 - XC^2) - 
        a^2 (b^2 + c^2 - 2 XA^2 + XB^2 + XC^2)), -2 a^2 b^2 c^2 - 
     2 a^4 XA^2 + 2 a^2 b^2 XA^2 + 2 a^2 c^2 XA^2 - 2 a^2 XA^4 + 
     2 a^2 b^2 XB^2 - 2 b^4 XB^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 XB^2 + 2 a^2 XA^2 XB^2 + 
     2 b^2 XA^2 XB^2 - 2 c^2 XA^2 XB^2 - 2 b^2 XB^4 + 
     2 a^2 c^2 XC^2 + 2 b^2 c^2 XC^2 - 2 c^4 XC^2 + 2 a^2 XA^2 XC^2 - 
     2 b^2 XA^2 XC^2 + 2 c^2 XA^2 XC^2 - 2 a^2 XB^2 XC^2 + 
     2 b^2 XB^2 XC^2 + 2 c^2 XB^2 XC^2 - 
     2 c^2 XC^4}, {recip*(XA + (XB + c)) - 1}];

Elimination of two variables, retaining symbolic parameters, is now feasible. To speed it I use an undocumented early termination option known as "sudden death" in the Groebner walk literature (B. Amrhein, O. Gloor, and W. Küchlin. On the walk. Theoretical Computer Science 187:179−202. 1997.) Note: I have not tested without that option so I do not know for certain that it is faster than all alternatives.
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, XA, {recip, XB, XC}, 
   CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions, 
   MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder, 
   Method -> {"GroebnerWalk", "EarlyEliminate" -> True}]

(* Out[33]= {a^12 b^4 c - 17 a^10 b^6 c - 6 a^9 b^7 c + 
   76 a^8 b^8 c + 24 a^7 b^9 c - 154 a^6 b^10 c - 36 a^5 b^11 c + 
   161 a^4 b^12 c + 24 a^3 b^13 c - 85 a^2 b^14 c - 6 a b^15 c + 
   18 b^16 c + 2 a^11 b^4 c^2 - 16 a^10 b^5 c^2 - 42 a^9 b^6 c^2 + 
   200 a^8 b^7 c^2 + 228 a^7 b^8 c^2 - 720 a^6 b^9 c^2 - 
   452 a^5 b^10 c^2 + 1120 a^4 b^11 c^2 + 378 a^3 b^12 c^2 - 
   800 a^2 b^13 c^2 - 114 a b^14 c^2 + 216 b^15 c^2 - 
   19 a^10 b^4 c^3 - 42 a^9 b^5 c^3 + 380 a^8 b^6 c^3 + 
   688 a^7 b^7 c^3 - 1810 a^6 b^8 c^3 - 2180 a^5 b^9 c^3 + 
   3708 a^4 b^10 c^3 + 2464 a^3 b^11 c^3 - 3411 a^2 b^12 c^3 - 
   930 a b^13 c^3 + 1152 b^14 c^3 - 38 a^9 b^4 c^4 + 
   224 a^8 b^5 c^4 + 976 a^7 b^6 c^4 - 2296 a^6 b^7 c^4 - 
   5052 a^5 b^8 c^4 + 7032 a^4 b^9 c^4 + 8032 a^3 b^10 c^4 - 
   8776 a^2 b^11 c^4 - 3918 a b^12 c^4 + 3816 b^13 c^4 + 
   96 a^8 b^4 c^5 + 520 a^7 b^5 c^5 - 2022 a^6 b^6 c^5 - 
   6508 a^5 b^7 c^5 + 9022 a^4 b^8 c^5 + 15840 a^3 b^9 c^5 - 
   15706 a^2 b^10 c^5 - 10332 a b^11 c^5 + 9090 b^12 c^5 + 
   156 a^7 b^4 c^6 - 952 a^6 b^5 c^6 - 4540 a^5 b^6 c^6 + 
   8464 a^4 b^7 c^6 + 19988 a^3 b^8 c^6 - 21064 a^2 b^9 c^6 - 
   18612 a b^10 c^6 + 16560 b^11 c^6 - 238 a^6 b^4 c^7 - 
   1580 a^5 b^5 c^7 + 5356 a^4 b^6 c^7 + 15744 a^3 b^7 c^7 - 
   21198 a^2 b^8 c^7 - 23268 a b^9 c^7 + 23184 b^10 c^7 - 
   260 a^5 b^4 c^8 + 1944 a^4 b^5 c^8 + 7248 a^3 b^6 c^8 - 
   15128 a^2 b^7 c^8 - 19740 a b^8 c^8 + 24336 b^9 c^8 + 
   313 a^4 b^4 c^9 + 1768 a^3 b^5 c^9 - 7009 a^2 b^6 c^9 - 
   10878 a b^7 c^9 + 18486 b^8 c^9 + 194 a^3 b^4 c^10 - 
   1848 a^2 b^5 c^10 - 3642 a b^6 c^10 + 9720 b^7 c^10 - 
   207 a^2 b^4 c^11 - 666 a b^5 c^11 + 3312 b^6 c^11 - 
   54 a b^4 c^12 + 648 b^5 c^12 + 
   54 b^4 c^13 + (4 a^12 b^4 - 8 a^11 b^5 - 44 a^10 b^6 + 
      40 a^9 b^7 + 160 a^8 b^8 - 80 a^7 b^9 - 280 a^6 b^10 + 
      80 a^5 b^11 + 260 a^4 b^12 - 40 a^3 b^13 - 124 a^2 b^14 + 
      8 a b^15 + 24 b^16 + 10 a^12 b^3 c + 60 a^11 b^4 c - 
      208 a^10 b^5 c - 484 a^9 b^6 c + 994 a^8 b^7 c + 
      1368 a^7 b^8 c - 2128 a^6 b^9 c - 1800 a^5 b^10 c + 
      2350 a^4 b^11 c + 1132 a^3 b^12 c - 1312 a^2 b^13 c - 
      276 a b^14 c + 294 b^15 c + 4 a^11 b^3 c^2 - 90 a^10 b^4 c^2 - 
      848 a^9 b^5 c^2 + 1346 a^8 b^6 c^2 + 4728 a^7 b^7 c^2 - 
      5412 a^6 b^8 c^2 - 9328 a^5 b^9 c^2 + 9252 a^4 b^10 c^2 + 
      7844 a^3 b^11 c^2 - 7202 a^2 b^12 c^2 - 2400 a b^13 c^2 + 
      2106 b^14 c^2 - 174 a^10 b^3 c^3 - 768 a^9 b^4 c^3 + 
      1886 a^8 b^5 c^3 + 8224 a^7 b^6 c^3 - 9516 a^6 b^7 c^3 - 
      24128 a^5 b^8 c^3 + 23100 a^4 b^9 c^3 + 27040 a^3 b^10 c^3 - 
      24710 a^2 b^11 c^3 - 10368 a b^12 c^3 + 9414 b^13 c^3 - 
      124 a^9 b^3 c^4 + 1310 a^8 b^4 c^4 + 8432 a^7 b^5 c^4 - 
      11328 a^6 b^6 c^4 - 40744 a^5 b^7 c^4 + 39372 a^4 b^8 c^4 + 
      62704 a^3 b^9 c^4 - 56848 a^2 b^10 c^4 - 30524 a b^11 c^4 + 
      27750 b^12 c^4 + 800 a^8 b^3 c^5 + 3864 a^7 b^4 c^5 - 
      9528 a^6 b^5 c^5 - 42488 a^5 b^6 c^5 + 47416 a^4 b^7 c^5 + 
      99144 a^3 b^8 c^5 - 93544 a^2 b^9 c^5 - 64104 a b^10 c^5 + 
      58440 b^11 c^5 + 504 a^7 b^3 c^6 - 5476 a^6 b^4 c^6 - 
      27152 a^5 b^5 c^6 + 41004 a^4 b^6 c^6 + 107352 a^3 b^7 c^6 - 
      114284 a^2 b^8 c^6 - 97088 a b^9 c^6 + 93540 b^10 c^6 - 
      1708 a^6 b^3 c^7 - 8256 a^5 b^4 c^7 + 25188 a^4 b^5 c^7 + 
      78240 a^3 b^6 c^7 - 103652 a^2 b^7 c^7 - 107136 a b^8 c^7 + 
      116364 b^9 c^7 - 808 a^5 b^3 c^8 + 10080 a^4 b^4 c^8 + 
      34808 a^3 b^5 c^8 - 67972 a^2 b^6 c^8 - 85008 a b^7 c^8 + 
      110916 b^8 c^8 + 1914 a^4 b^3 c^9 + 7692 a^3 b^4 c^9 - 
      30664 a^2 b^5 c^9 - 45924 a b^6 c^9 + 78390 b^7 c^9 + 
      580 a^3 b^3 c^10 - 8546 a^2 b^4 c^10 - 15232 a b^5 c^10 + 
      39426 b^6 c^10 - 1094 a^2 b^3 c^11 - 2592 a b^4 c^11 + 
      13326 b^5 c^11 - 156 a b^3 c^12 + 2718 b^4 c^12 + 
      252 b^3 c^13) XA + (40 a^12 b^3 + 32 a^11 b^4 - 336 a^10 b^5 - 
      288 a^9 b^6 + 1016 a^8 b^7 + 832 a^7 b^8 - 1504 a^6 b^9 - 
      1088 a^5 b^10 + 1176 a^4 b^11 + 672 a^3 b^12 - 464 a^2 b^13 - 
      160 a b^14 + 72 b^15 + 33 a^12 b^2 c + 440 a^11 b^3 c - 
      356 a^10 b^4 c - 3252 a^9 b^5 c + 1693 a^8 b^6 c + 
      9280 a^7 b^7 c - 3968 a^6 b^8 c - 12600 a^5 b^9 c + 
      4683 a^4 b^10 c + 8168 a^3 b^11 c - 2652 a^2 b^12 c - 
      2036 a b^13 c + 567 b^14 c - 30 a^11 b^2 c^2 - 
      436 a^10 b^3 c^2 - 4294 a^9 b^4 c^2 + 2536 a^8 b^5 c^2 + 
      24740 a^7 b^6 c^2 - 6872 a^6 b^7 c^2 - 48668 a^5 b^8 c^2 + 
      11296 a^4 b^9 c^2 + 39930 a^3 b^10 c^2 - 9428 a^2 b^11 c^2 - 
      11678 a b^12 c^2 + 2904 b^13 c^2 - 467 a^10 b^2 c^3 - 
      3682 a^9 b^3 c^3 + 2463 a^8 b^4 c^3 + 33848 a^7 b^5 c^3 - 
      7182 a^6 b^6 c^3 - 94492 a^5 b^7 c^3 + 20494 a^4 b^8 c^3 + 
      100504 a^3 b^9 c^3 - 28111 a^2 b^10 c^3 - 35666 a b^11 c^3 + 
      12291 b^12 c^3 + 26 a^9 b^2 c^4 + 3116 a^8 b^3 c^4 + 
      28568 a^7 b^4 c^4 - 11872 a^6 b^5 c^4 - 127044 a^5 b^6 c^4 + 
      33176 a^4 b^7 c^4 + 174040 a^3 b^8 c^4 - 62144 a^2 b^9 c^4 - 
      73542 a b^10 c^4 + 35676 b^11 c^4 + 1952 a^8 b^2 c^5 + 
      12312 a^7 b^3 c^5 - 12764 a^6 b^4 c^5 - 116288 a^5 b^5 c^5 + 
      42996 a^4 b^6 c^5 + 228952 a^3 b^7 c^5 - 95956 a^2 b^8 c^5 - 
      118512 a b^9 c^5 + 68508 b^10 c^5 + 220 a^7 b^2 c^6 - 
      10624 a^6 b^3 c^6 - 69516 a^5 b^4 c^6 + 47480 a^4 b^5 c^6 + 
      225988 a^3 b^6 c^6 - 114416 a^2 b^7 c^6 - 155092 a b^8 c^6 + 
      95160 b^9 c^6 - 3822 a^6 b^2 c^7 - 19772 a^5 b^3 c^7 + 
      35610 a^4 b^4 c^7 + 160072 a^3 b^5 c^7 - 112170 a^2 b^6 c^7 - 
      162604 a b^7 c^7 + 108318 b^8 c^7 - 516 a^5 b^2 c^8 + 
      17464 a^4 b^3 c^8 + 71784 a^3 b^4 c^8 - 83360 a^2 b^5 c^8 - 
      131428 a b^6 c^8 + 105960 b^7 c^8 + 3929 a^4 b^2 c^9 + 
      15136 a^3 b^3 c^9 - 42440 a^2 b^4 c^9 - 75340 a b^5 c^9 + 
      82695 b^6 c^9 + 418 a^3 b^2 c^10 - 13580 a^2 b^3 c^10 - 
      26574 a b^4 c^10 + 46512 b^5 c^10 - 2063 a^2 b^2 c^11 - 
      4434 a b^3 c^11 + 17487 b^4 c^11 - 118 a b^2 c^12 + 
      4020 b^3 c^12 + 438 b^2 c^13) XA^2 + (132 a^12 b^2 + 
      472 a^11 b^3 - 584 a^10 b^4 - 2872 a^9 b^5 + 364 a^8 b^6 + 
      6256 a^7 b^7 + 1488 a^6 b^8 - 6256 a^5 b^9 - 2788 a^4 b^10 + 
      2872 a^3 b^11 + 1784 a^2 b^12 - 472 a b^13 - 396 b^14 + 
      40 a^12 b c + 1020 a^11 b^2 c + 1068 a^10 b^3 c - 
      7868 a^9 b^4 c - 7588 a^8 b^5 c + 21656 a^7 b^6 c + 
      18680 a^6 b^7 c - 26424 a^5 b^8 c - 23328 a^4 b^9 c + 
      14252 a^3 b^10 c + 15388 a^2 b^11 c - 2636 a b^12 c - 
      4260 b^13 c - 64 a^11 b c^2 - 954 a^10 b^2 c^2 - 
      8756 a^9 b^3 c^2 - 7082 a^8 b^4 c^2 + 41904 a^7 b^5 c^2 + 
      42700 a^6 b^6 c^2 - 69720 a^5 b^7 c^2 - 78372 a^4 b^8 c^2 + 
      47024 a^3 b^9 c^2 + 66862 a^2 b^10 c^2 - 10388 a b^11 c^2 - 
      23154 b^12 c^2 - 488 a^10 b c^3 - 7340 a^9 b^2 c^3 - 
      5732 a^8 b^3 c^3 + 55184 a^7 b^4 c^3 + 60896 a^6 b^5 c^3 - 
      121832 a^5 b^6 c^3 - 159416 a^4 b^7 c^3 + 98512 a^3 b^8 c^3 + 
      177896 a^2 b^9 c^3 - 22476 a b^10 c^3 - 75204 b^11 c^3 + 
      272 a^9 b c^4 + 3422 a^8 b^2 c^4 + 42912 a^7 b^3 c^4 + 
      42088 a^6 b^4 c^4 - 141568 a^5 b^5 c^4 - 198444 a^4 b^6 c^4 + 
      127200 a^3 b^7 c^4 + 306216 a^2 b^8 c^4 - 16016 a b^9 c^4 - 
      160962 b^10 c^4 + 1888 a^8 b c^5 + 20360 a^7 b^2 c^5 + 
      10024 a^6 b^3 c^5 - 136920 a^5 b^4 c^5 - 164568 a^4 b^5 c^5 + 
      148952 a^3 b^6 c^5 + 375352 a^2 b^7 c^5 + 9336 a b^8 c^5 - 
      256488 b^9 c^5 - 448 a^7 b c^6 - 7924 a^6 b^2 c^6 - 
      84792 a^5 b^3 c^6 - 69308 a^4 b^4 c^6 + 162320 a^3 b^5 c^6 + 
      327700 a^2 b^6 c^6 + 12328 a b^7 c^6 - 324516 b^8 c^6 - 
      3472 a^6 b c^7 - 27368 a^5 b^2 c^7 - 2232 a^4 b^3 c^7 + 
      139312 a^3 b^4 c^7 + 178592 a^2 b^5 c^7 - 19016 a b^6 c^7 - 
      310680 b^7 c^7 + 352 a^5 b c^8 + 10928 a^4 b^2 c^8 + 
      73000 a^3 b^3 c^8 + 43280 a^2 b^4 c^8 - 50184 a b^5 c^8 - 
      202080 b^6 c^8 + 3368 a^4 b c^9 + 17916 a^3 b^2 c^9 - 
      7508 a^2 b^3 c^9 - 48172 a b^4 c^9 - 76932 b^5 c^9 - 
      128 a^3 b c^10 - 7794 a^2 b^2 c^10 - 22836 a b^3 c^10 - 
      9930 b^4 c^10 - 1672 a^2 b c^11 - 4588 a b^2 c^11 + 
      4380 b^3 c^11 + 16 a b c^12 + 2190 b^2 c^12 + 
      336 b c^13) XA^3 + (160 a^12 b + 1072 a^11 b^2 + 
      1360 a^10 b^3 - 3760 a^9 b^4 - 9648 a^8 b^5 + 2272 a^7 b^6 + 
      20768 a^6 b^7 + 5024 a^5 b^8 - 20416 a^4 b^9 - 7184 a^3 b^10 + 
      9360 a^2 b^11 + 2576 a b^12 - 1584 b^13 + 16 a^12 c + 
      960 a^11 b c + 3497 a^10 b^2 c - 6030 a^9 b^3 c - 
      28839 a^8 b^4 c + 2552 a^7 b^5 c + 79330 a^6 b^6 c + 
      26668 a^5 b^7 c - 100998 a^4 b^8 c - 41672 a^3 b^9 c + 
      61781 a^2 b^10 c + 17522 a b^11 c - 14787 b^12 c - 
      32 a^11 c^2 - 880 a^10 b c^2 - 8196 a^9 b^2 c^2 - 
      33388 a^8 b^3 c^2 - 6304 a^7 b^4 c^2 + 156288 a^6 b^5 c^2 + 
      99000 a^5 b^6 c^2 - 265624 a^4 b^7 c^2 - 149984 a^3 b^8 c^2 + 
      214416 a^2 b^9 c^2 + 65516 a b^10 c^2 - 70812 b^11 c^2 - 
      176 a^10 c^3 - 6496 a^9 b c^3 - 19497 a^8 b^2 c^3 + 
      19592 a^7 b^3 c^3 + 171924 a^6 b^4 c^3 + 108568 a^5 b^5 c^3 - 
      434230 a^4 b^6 c^3 - 264136 a^3 b^7 c^3 + 488900 a^2 b^8 c^3 + 
      138120 a b^9 c^3 - 217929 b^10 c^3 + 160 a^9 c^4 + 
      1616 a^8 b c^4 + 25896 a^7 b^2 c^4 + 131720 a^6 b^3 c^4 + 
      84408 a^5 b^4 c^4 - 508424 a^4 b^5 c^4 - 360104 a^3 b^6 c^4 + 
      766584 a^2 b^7 c^4 + 231976 a b^8 c^4 - 442440 b^9 c^4 + 
      640 a^8 c^5 + 16640 a^7 b c^5 + 44066 a^6 b^2 c^5 - 
      12340 a^5 b^3 c^5 - 408458 a^4 b^4 c^5 - 335096 a^3 b^5 c^5 + 
      867390 a^2 b^6 c^5 + 340876 a b^7 c^5 - 628662 b^8 c^5 - 
      320 a^7 c^6 - 1120 a^6 b c^6 - 37984 a^5 b^2 c^6 - 
      216576 a^4 b^3 c^6 - 176880 a^3 b^4 c^6 + 748560 a^2 b^5 c^6 + 
      365584 a b^6 c^6 - 692016 b^7 c^6 - 1120 a^6 c^7 - 
      20544 a^5 b c^7 - 51178 a^4 b^2 c^7 - 18808 a^3 b^3 c^7 + 
      453716 a^2 b^4 c^7 + 259624 a b^5 c^7 - 619242 b^6 c^7 + 
      320 a^5 c^8 + 64 a^4 b c^8 + 25192 a^3 b^2 c^8 + 
      173064 a^2 b^3 c^8 + 112136 a b^4 c^8 - 422424 b^5 c^8 + 
      1040 a^4 c^9 + 12352 a^3 b c^9 + 31173 a^2 b^2 c^9 + 
      18610 a b^3 c^9 - 197943 b^4 c^9 - 160 a^3 c^10 + 
      208 a^2 b c^10 - 5980 a b^2 c^10 - 57204 b^3 c^10 - 
      496 a^2 c^11 - 2912 a b c^11 - 8061 b^2 c^11 + 32 a c^12 - 
      48 b c^12 + 96 c^13) XA^4 + (64 a^12 + 896 a^11 b + 
      6228 a^10 b^2 + 6016 a^9 b^3 - 23844 a^8 b^4 - 31872 a^7 b^5 + 
      32072 a^6 b^6 + 50560 a^5 b^7 - 16392 a^4 b^8 - 34048 a^3 b^9 + 
      420 a^2 b^10 + 8448 a b^11 + 1452 b^12 + 320 a^11 c + 
      3304 a^10 b c + 7576 a^9 b^2 c - 25808 a^8 b^3 c - 
      66496 a^7 b^4 c + 59536 a^6 b^5 c + 161840 a^5 b^6 c - 
      51168 a^4 b^7 c - 160704 a^3 b^8 c + 2760 a^2 b^9 c + 
      57464 a b^10 c + 11376 b^11 c - 288 a^10 c^2 - 3312 a^9 b c^2 - 
      48532 a^8 b^2 c^2 - 93568 a^7 b^3 c^2 + 144848 a^6 b^4 c^2 + 
      346336 a^5 b^5 c^2 - 144888 a^4 b^6 c^2 - 437632 a^3 b^7 c^2 + 
      13936 a^2 b^8 c^2 + 189200 a b^9 c^2 + 33900 b^10 c^2 - 
      2112 a^9 c^3 - 19096 a^8 b c^3 - 52544 a^7 b^2 c^3 + 
      133760 a^6 b^3 c^3 + 420448 a^5 b^4 c^3 - 186192 a^4 b^5 c^3 - 
      740992 a^3 b^6 c^3 + 8704 a^2 b^7 c^3 + 366496 a b^8 c^3 + 
      51048 b^9 c^3 + 224 a^8 c^4 + 1024 a^7 b c^4 + 
      135240 a^6 b^2 c^4 + 315648 a^5 b^3 c^4 - 269592 a^4 b^4 c^4 - 
      808960 a^3 b^5 c^4 + 62232 a^2 b^6 c^4 + 467456 a b^7 c^4 + 
      36312 b^8 c^4 + 5248 a^7 c^5 + 42512 a^6 b c^5 + 
      128112 a^5 b^2 c^5 - 259616 a^4 b^3 c^5 - 703360 a^3 b^4 c^5 + 
      133168 a^2 b^5 c^5 + 518800 a b^6 c^5 + 42720 b^7 c^5 + 
      704 a^6 c^6 + 8864 a^5 b c^6 - 180712 a^4 b^2 c^6 - 
      392576 a^3 b^3 c^6 + 246480 a^2 b^4 c^6 + 500128 a b^5 c^6 + 
      59736 b^6 c^6 - 6272 a^5 c^7 - 47024 a^4 b c^7 - 
      132480 a^3 b^2 c^7 + 239616 a^2 b^3 c^7 + 348128 a b^4 c^7 - 
      12144 b^5 c^7 - 1536 a^4 c^8 - 12032 a^3 b c^8 + 
      122276 a^2 b^2 c^8 + 163456 a b^3 c^8 - 96612 b^4 c^8 + 
      3648 a^3 c^9 + 26376 a^2 b c^9 + 49336 a b^2 c^9 - 
      86928 b^3 c^9 + 1120 a^2 c^10 + 4560 a b c^10 - 
      34500 b^2 c^10 - 832 a c^11 - 6072 b c^11 - 
      288 c^12) XA^5 + (256 a^11 + 7456 a^10 b + 12992 a^9 b^2 - 
      13344 a^8 b^3 - 39168 a^7 b^4 - 20160 a^6 b^5 + 30848 a^5 b^6 + 
      62912 a^4 b^7 + 2560 a^3 b^8 - 49248 a^2 b^9 - 7488 a b^10 + 
      12384 b^11 + 1040 a^10 c + 15168 a^9 b c + 9260 a^8 b^2 c - 
      97632 a^7 b^3 c - 119792 a^6 b^4 c + 162208 a^5 b^5 c + 
      292008 a^4 b^6 c - 90656 a^3 b^7 c - 277632 a^2 b^8 c + 
      8864 a b^9 c + 97164 b^10 c - 384 a^9 c^2 - 31232 a^8 b c^2 - 
      85248 a^7 b^2 c^2 - 92192 a^6 b^3 c^2 + 188672 a^5 b^4 c^2 + 
      492640 a^4 b^5 c^2 - 168704 a^3 b^6 c^2 - 674912 a^2 b^7 c^2 + 
      92288 a b^8 c^2 + 340512 b^9 c^2 - 6288 a^8 c^3 - 
      67840 a^7 b c^3 - 46464 a^6 b^2 c^3 + 326656 a^5 b^3 c^3 + 
      575744 a^4 b^4 c^3 - 392832 a^3 b^5 c^3 - 1113280 a^2 b^6 c^3 + 
      255360 a b^7 c^3 + 738768 b^8 c^3 - 3072 a^7 c^4 + 
      51136 a^6 b c^4 + 195936 a^5 b^2 c^4 + 410688 a^4 b^3 c^4 - 
      328000 a^3 b^4 c^4 - 1332672 a^2 b^5 c^4 + 245216 a b^6 c^4 + 
      1068480 b^7 c^4 + 13728 a^6 c^5 + 117632 a^5 b c^5 + 
      103512 a^4 b^2 c^5 - 362336 a^3 b^3 c^5 - 1075888 a^2 b^4 c^5 + 
      128480 a b^5 c^5 + 1143288 b^6 c^5 + 8960 a^5 c^6 - 
      39552 a^4 b c^6 - 181824 a^3 b^2 c^6 - 562592 a^2 b^3 c^6 + 
      131136 a b^4 c^6 + 1009056 b^5 c^6 - 13856 a^4 c^7 - 
      92416 a^3 b c^7 - 109920 a^2 b^2 c^7 + 119744 a b^3 c^7 + 
      667296 b^4 c^7 - 8448 a^3 c^8 + 13344 a^2 b c^8 + 
      56096 a b^2 c^8 + 271008 b^3 c^8 + 6480 a^2 c^9 + 
      27456 a b c^9 + 45660 b^2 c^9 + 2688 a c^10 - 1152 b c^10 - 
      1104 c^11) XA^6 + (2880 a^10 + 5248 a^9 b + 22208 a^8 b^2 + 
      21120 a^7 b^3 - 91136 a^6 b^4 - 94848 a^5 b^5 + 
      116480 a^4 b^6 + 113536 a^3 b^7 - 58688 a^2 b^8 - 45056 a b^9 + 
      8256 b^10 + 6656 a^9 c + 22336 a^8 b c - 26048 a^7 b^2 c - 
      184448 a^6 b^3 c - 55232 a^5 b^4 c + 422656 a^4 b^5 c + 
      256192 a^3 b^6 c - 314752 a^2 b^7 c - 189760 a b^8 c + 
      62400 b^9 c - 7616 a^8 c^2 - 7360 a^7 b c^2 - 
      237376 a^6 b^2 c^2 - 220352 a^5 b^3 c^2 + 759360 a^4 b^4 c^2 + 
      576448 a^3 b^5 c^2 - 740288 a^2 b^6 c^2 - 356928 a b^7 c^2 + 
      254592 b^8 c^2 - 24576 a^7 c^3 - 101952 a^6 b c^3 - 
      28224 a^5 b^2 c^3 + 675904 a^4 b^3 c^3 + 575104 a^3 b^4 c^3 - 
      860352 a^2 b^5 c^3 - 401472 a b^6 c^3 + 527040 b^7 c^3 + 
      2688 a^6 c^4 - 27072 a^5 b c^4 + 562752 a^4 b^2 c^4 + 
      476160 a^3 b^3 c^4 - 1098112 a^2 b^4 c^4 - 406080 a b^5 c^4 + 
      728256 b^6 c^4 + 33792 a^5 c^5 + 173120 a^4 b c^5 + 
      138432 a^3 b^2 c^5 - 848384 a^2 b^3 c^5 - 494016 a b^4 c^5 + 
      633792 b^5 c^5 + 8832 a^4 c^6 + 59328 a^3 b c^6 - 
      540864 a^2 b^2 c^6 - 296896 a b^3 c^6 + 485952 b^4 c^6 - 
      20480 a^3 c^7 - 133824 a^2 b c^7 - 88256 a b^2 c^7 + 
      376896 b^3 c^7 - 9664 a^2 c^8 - 30144 a b c^8 + 
      197376 b^2 c^8 + 4608 a c^9 + 40320 b c^9 + 
      2880 c^10) XA^7 + (-512 a^9 + 33664 a^8 b + 45824 a^7 b^2 - 
      68352 a^6 b^3 - 112896 a^5 b^4 + 90368 a^3 b^6 + 
      70400 a^2 b^7 - 22784 a b^8 - 35712 b^9 + 7744 a^8 c + 
      37760 a^7 b c - 21536 a^6 b^2 c - 204352 a^5 b^3 c - 
      80736 a^4 b^4 c + 384512 a^3 b^5 c + 287520 a^2 b^6 c - 
      258368 a b^7 c - 213984 b^8 c + 12288 a^7 c^2 - 
      132736 a^6 b c^2 - 221568 a^5 b^2 c^2 + 130944 a^4 b^3 c^2 + 
      570368 a^3 b^4 c^2 + 203136 a^2 b^5 c^2 - 639616 a b^6 c^2 - 
      475776 b^7 c^2 - 33280 a^6 c^3 - 140416 a^5 b c^3 + 
      38688 a^4 b^2 c^3 + 750720 a^3 b^3 c^3 + 593600 a^2 b^4 c^3 - 
      826624 a b^5 c^3 - 717792 b^6 c^3 - 41984 a^5 c^4 + 
      185984 a^4 b c^4 + 407680 a^3 b^2 c^4 + 367744 a^2 b^3 c^4 - 
      539008 a b^4 c^4 - 724992 b^5 c^4 + 49280 a^4 c^5 + 
      167552 a^3 b c^5 + 104096 a^2 b^2 c^5 - 483648 a b^3 c^5 - 
      594912 b^4 c^5 + 49152 a^3 c^6 - 108416 a^2 b c^6 - 
      233472 a b^2 c^6 - 462336 b^3 c^6 - 29696 a^2 c^7 - 
      64896 a b c^7 - 119712 b^2 c^7 - 18944 a c^8 + 21504 b c^8 + 
      5952 c^9) XA^8 + (12800 a^8 + 8192 a^7 b + 9600 a^6 b^2 - 
      136320 a^4 b^4 - 73728 a^3 b^5 + 177280 a^2 b^6 + 65536 a b^7 - 
      63360 b^8 + 21504 a^7 c + 64512 a^6 b c - 143360 a^5 b^2 c - 
      427264 a^4 b^3 c + 97792 a^3 b^4 c + 633856 a^2 b^5 c + 
      42496 a b^6 c - 289536 b^7 c - 20992 a^6 c^2 + 
      13056 a^5 b c^2 - 357248 a^4 b^2 c^2 - 171520 a^3 b^3 c^2 + 
      653056 a^2 b^4 c^2 - 183552 a b^5 c^2 - 697728 b^6 c^2 - 
      48128 a^5 c^3 - 212736 a^4 b c^3 + 220672 a^3 b^2 c^3 + 
      784896 a^2 b^3 c^3 - 370688 a b^4 c^3 - 890112 b^5 c^3 - 
      5632 a^4 c^4 - 23040 a^3 b c^4 + 761472 a^2 b^2 c^4 + 
      48640 a b^3 c^4 - 899712 b^4 c^4 + 31744 a^3 c^5 + 
      278016 a^2 b c^5 - 59904 a b^2 c^5 - 460032 b^3 c^5 + 
      23040 a^2 c^6 + 1792 a b c^6 - 431232 b^2 c^6 - 5120 a c^7 - 
      129792 b c^7 - 9216 c^8) XA^9 + (-6144 a^7 + 30208 a^6 b + 
      33792 a^5 b^2 - 88576 a^4 b^3 - 114688 a^3 b^4 + 
      53760 a^2 b^5 + 87040 a b^6 + 4608 b^7 + 22272 a^6 c - 
      36864 a^5 b c - 161152 a^4 b^2 c - 45568 a^3 b^3 c + 
      200192 a^2 b^4 c + 314880 a b^5 c + 102528 b^6 c + 
      43008 a^5 c^2 - 191488 a^4 b c^2 - 389632 a^3 b^2 c^2 + 
      194048 a^2 b^3 c^2 + 476672 a b^4 c^2 + 66048 b^5 c^2 - 
      63744 a^4 c^3 - 16384 a^3 b c^3 - 44800 a^2 b^2 c^3 + 
      80384 a b^3 c^3 + 115200 b^4 c^3 - 67584 a^3 c^4 + 
      235008 a^2 b c^4 + 316416 a b^2 c^4 - 75264 b^3 c^4 + 
      60672 a^2 c^5 + 53248 a b c^5 + 183936 b^2 c^5 + 30720 a c^6 - 
      73728 b c^6 - 19200 c^7) XA^10 + (9216 a^6 + 6144 a^5 b + 
      12288 a^4 b^2 - 36864 a^3 b^3 - 119808 a^2 b^4 + 30720 a b^5 + 
      98304 b^6 + 58368 a^4 b c + 61440 a^3 b^2 c - 64512 a^2 b^3 c + 
      159744 a b^4 c + 276480 b^5 c - 9216 a^4 c^2 - 
      119808 a^3 b c^2 - 115200 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 485376 a b^3 c^2 + 
      532992 b^4 c^2 - 248832 a^2 b c^3 - 6144 a b^2 c^3 + 
      380928 b^3 c^3 - 9216 a^2 c^4 + 113664 a b c^4 + 
      170496 b^2 c^4 + 190464 b c^5 + 
      9216 c^6) XA^11 + (18432 a^4 b - 110592 a^2 b^3 + 92160 b^5 + 
      27648 a^4 c + 55296 a^3 b c + 57600 a^2 b^2 c - 69120 a b^3 c - 
      52992 b^4 c - 55296 a^2 b c^2 + 138240 a b^2 c^2 + 
      267264 b^3 c^2 - 55296 a^2 c^3 - 55296 a b c^3 + 
      16128 b^2 c^3 + 36864 b c^4 + 
      27648 c^5) XA^12 + (-27648 a^2 b^2 + 27648 b^4 + 
      55296 a^2 b c - 55296 a b^2 c - 221184 b^3 c + 27648 b^2 c^2 - 
      55296 b c^3) XA^13 - 82944 b^2 c XA^14} *)


Very elegant (+1).  Note that factoring Out[33] reduces its LeafCount greatly, and the final factor is the eighth-order polynomial I derived in my answer.  Where can I find more information on this and other undocumented GroebnerBasis options?  Thanks.

@bbgodfrey For a bit more on "EarlyEliminate see this notebook on implicitization or this MSE post or this one and the comments. There may be others as well.

I think I will stay away from obscure method suboptions. Another undocumented useful option is "DegreeBound". Here is an MSE post with an example of usage. Also it should be in the source code for the Wolfram Resource Repository function ExtendedGroebnerBasis.

This problem also can be solved by brut force, but doing so reqauires a several-hour computation.
sol = GroebnerBasis[system, {XA, XB, XC}, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions] // Factor
LeafCount /@ sol
(* {2585, 1400662, 6727532} *)

Count[sol[[1]], #, Infinity] & /@ {XA, XB, XC}
(* {0, 4, 213} *)
Count[sol[[2]], #, Infinity] & /@ {XA, XB, XC}
(* {0, 6277, 91960} *)
Count[sol[[3]], #, Infinity] & /@ {XA, XB, XC}
(* {9111, 286118, 418790} *)

Thus, sol would be a "regular chain" solution requested in the question, were it not for the four instances of XB in sol[[1]].  They can be isolated by
Most[sol[[1]]]
(* XC^2 (a + XC) (b + XC) 
   (a^3 + 3 a b^2 - 2 a b c - a c^2 + 4 a^2 XC + 4 b^2 XC - 4 c^2 XC + 4 a XC^2) 
   (3 a^2 b + b^3 - 2 a b c - b c^2 + 4 a^2 XC + 4 b^2 XC - 4 c^2 XC + 4 b XC^2) 
   (a^2 c + a^2 XB - b^2 XB + c^2 XB + c XB^2 - c XC^2) *)
Most[sol[[2]]]
(* -a^2 c - a^2 XB + b^2 XB - c^2 XB - c XB^2 + c XC^2 *)

sol[[3]] has only one factor.  Because the factor (a^2 c + a^2 XB - b^2 XB + c^2 XB + c XB^2 - c XC^2) appears in both sol[[1]] and sol[2]], it has an infinite number of solutions in {XB, XC}, with a corresponding XA determined by sol[[3]].  Removing this factor from Most@sol (suing PolynomialQuotient, for instance) then does give a "regular chain" solution.
Specific solutions are obtain by, as an example,
Solve[Join[Thread[sol == 0] /. {a -> 3, b -> 4, c -> 5}, {XA > 0, XB > 0, XC > 0}]]
    // RootReduce


For completeness,
sol1 = GroebnerBasis[system, {XC, XB, XA}, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions] // Factor

gives an alternative form for the general solution. Of course, this alternative representation also includes an infinite set of solutions, here associated with the common factor c + XA + XB, also identified by Daniel Lichtblau.  It is related to the common factor for the general solution representation given earlier in this answer by
Resultant[c + XA + XB, sol1[[4]], XA] // Factor

